# Big elasticsearch query_string query

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have to search with more than 1500 string values in elasticsearch. I am creating the query using "query_string", but I am getting

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"Failed to parse query ...
```

> Details: Elasticsearch : elasticsearch-5.6.3 PHP SDK : version 5 Index
>   : 20 million data

Is it possible to fetch data using this much string values? How can I achieve this goal?
Note : Due to character restiriction of stackoverflow I have removed some conditions from the code. Some time I have to use around 2000 string values as search condition. This same query is working for 800 string values.

```
 $params =     Array
    (
        "index" => 'sample_2',
        "type" => 'sample_2',
        "body" => Array
            (
               "query" => Array
                    (
                        "query_string" => Array
                            (
                                'query' => '( filed_name:"WDR19" OR filed_name:"TTPA" OR filed_name:"COX3" OR filed_name:"IL12A" OR filed_name:"MYH10" OR filed_name:"TRNS1" OR filed_name:"GJA1" OR filed_name:"HACE1" OR filed_name:"KIAA1320" OR filed_name:"SPPRS" OR filed_name:"COX20" OR filed_name:"COX10" OR filed_name:"NDUFS4" OR filed_name:"AQDQ" OR filed_name:"CI-18" OR filed_name:"SURF1" OR filed_name:"CMT4K" OR filed_name:"NDUFS7" OR filed_name:"PSST" OR filed_name:"CI-20" OR filed_name:"CI-20KD" OR filed_name:"MY017" OR filed_name:"NDUFS8" OR filed_name:"CI-23k" OR filed_name:"CI23KD" OR filed_name:"TYKY" OR filed_name:"BCS1L" OR filed_name:"FLNMS" OR filed_name:"GRACILE" OR filed_name:"BJS" OR filed_name:"PTD" OR filed_name:"MC3DN1" OR filed_name:"BCS" OR filed_name:"BCS1" OR filed_name:"Hs.6719" OR filed_name:"h-BCS" OR filed_name:"h-BCS1" OR filed_name:"NDUFA10" OR filed_name:"CI-42KD" OR filed_name:"CI-42k" OR filed_name:"SDHA" OR filed_name:"SDH1" OR filed_name:"SDHF" OR filed_name:"CMD1GG" OR filed_name:"PGL5" OR filed_name:"FP" OR filed_name:"SDH2" OR filed_name:"NDUFAF6" OR filed_name:"H17" OR filed_name:"NDUFS3" OR filed_name:"CI-30" OR filed_name:"DKC1" OR filed_name:"LMNB1" OR filed_name:"HTRA1" OR filed_name:"GCK" OR filed_name:"NDUFV1" OR filed_name:"CEP41" OR filed_name:"MECP2" OR filed_name:"RTT" OR filed_name:"PPMX" OR filed_name:"MRX16" OR filed_name:"MRX79" OR filed_name:"AUTSX3" OR filed_name:"MRXSL" OR filed_name:"MRXS13" OR filed_name:"GFAP" OR filed_name:"TRNK" OR filed_name:"GABRG2" OR filed_name:"TMEM237" OR filed_name:"GLB1" OR filed_name:"TMEM67" OR filed_name:"APOPT1" OR filed_name:"DAO" OR filed_name:"DNAJC5" OR filed_name:"PRNP" OR filed_name:"CNTN1" OR filed_name:"SDHB" OR filed_name:"NPC2" OR filed_name:"CTNNA2" OR filed_name:"POLG" OR filed_name:"POLG1" OR filed_name:"POLGA" OR filed_name:"PEO" OR filed_name:"SANDO" OR filed_name:"SCAE" OR filed_name:"MTDPS4A" OR filed_name:"MTDPS4B" OR filed_name:"MIRAS" OR filed_name:"MDP1" OR filed_name:"APTX" OR filed_name:"ATN1" OR filed_name:"LYST" OR filed_name:"KIAA1005" OR filed_name:"JBTS7" OR filed_name:"MKS5" OR filed_name:"CORS3" OR filed_name:"FTM" OR filed_name:"NPHP8" OR filed_name:"PPP1R134" OR filed_name:"WDR81" OR filed_name:"SESAME" OR filed_name:"BIRK-10" OR filed_name:"KCNJ13-PEN" OR filed_name:"KIR1.2" OR filed_name:"KIR4.1" OR filed_name:"PMM2" OR filed_name:"SOX10" OR filed_name:"WS4" OR filed_name:"WS4C" OR filed_name:"PCWH" OR filed_name:"DOM" OR filed_name:"WS2E" OR filed_name:"NPHP4" OR filed_name:"EFNB3" OR filed_name:"ND4" OR filed_name:"UCHL1" OR filed_name:"COQ2" OR filed_name:"HLA-B" OR filed_name:"SLC17A5" OR filed_name:"SIASD" OR filed_name:"SLD" OR filed_name:"AST" OR filed_name:"ISSD"  filed_name:"MSU" OR filed_name:"OVD1A" OR filed_name:"DBT" OR filed_name:"BCATE2" OR filed_name:"BCKAD-E2" OR filed_name:"BCKADE2"  OR filed_name:"COX6B1" OR filed_name:"COX6B" OR filed_name:"COXG" OR filed_name:"COXVIb1" OR filed_name:"SCOD1" OR filed_name:"ERAP1" OR filed_name:"B9D1" OR filed_name:"C12orf65" OR filed_name:"COXPD7" OR filed_name:"SPG55" OR filed_name:"INPP5E" OR filed_name:"ARSA" OR filed_name:"NDUFV2" OR filed_name:"SNAP25" OR filed_name:"CMS18" OR filed_name:"RIC-4" OR filed_name:"RIC4" OR filed_name:"SEC9" OR filed_name:"SNAP" OR filed_name:"SNAP-25" OR filed_name:"SUP" OR filed_name:"bA416N4.2" OR filed_name:"dJ1068F16.2" OR filed_name:"EI24" OR filed_name:"DMXL2" OR filed_name:"RPL27A" OR filed_name:"GABRB3" OR filed_name:"ECA5" OR filed_name:"EIEE43" OR filed_name:"SHC1" OR filed_name:"GSS" OR filed_name:"BTD" OR filed_name:"RIC8A" OR filed_name:"KLRC4" OR filed_name:"SOD2" OR filed_name:"SPRY4" OR filed_name:"SUCLG1" OR filed_name:"TRNL1" OR filed_name:"PGM3" OR filed_name:"VLDLR" OR filed_name:"AFG3L2" OR filed_name:"SCA28" OR filed_name:"SPAX5" OR filed_name:"KCNC3" OR filed_name:"MBD5" OR filed_name:"TPK1" OR filed_name:"RNF216" OR filed_name:"SCAR20" OR filed_name:"RGS-PX2" OR filed_name:"GFI1" OR filed_name:"TP53" OR filed_name:"STAT4" OR filed_name:"FGFR1" OR filed_name:"FOXI1" OR filed_name:"C5orf42" OR filed_name:"JBTS17" OR filed_name:"OFD6" OR filed_name:"Hug" OR filed_name:"PCDH15" OR filed_name:"C10orf2" OR filed_name:"TWINKLE" OR filed_name:"PEOA3" OR filed_name:"IOSCA" OR filed_name:"MTDPS7" OR filed_name:"PRLTS5" OR filed_name:"ATXN8" OR filed_name:"PEO1" OR filed_name:"SCA8" OR filed_name:"TWINL" OR filed_name:"ATPAF2" OR filed_name:"ND4L" OR filed_name:"TERC" OR filed_name:"NELFA" OR filed_name:"TREX1" OR filed_name:"TMEM138" OR filed_name:"CPLX1" OR filed_name:"PTRH2" OR filed_name:"BIT1" OR filed_name:"IMNEPD" OR filed_name:"CFAP37" OR filed_name:"CGI-147" OR filed_name:"PTH" OR filed_name:"GABRA1" OR filed_name:"MORMS" OR filed_name:"JBTS1" OR filed_name:"CORS1" OR filed_name:"CPD4" OR filed_name:"PPI5PIV" OR filed_name:"pharbin" OR filed_name:"MKS1" OR filed_name:"LIG4" OR filed_name:"SLC19A2" OR filed_name:"SDHAF1" OR filed_name:"UCHL3" OR filed_name:"XPC" OR filed_name:"DCX" OR filed_name:"GNAS" OR filed_name:"VIPR1" OR filed_name:"DCC" OR filed_name:"ATM" OR filed_name:"CA8" OR filed_name:"MTTP" OR filed_name:"ERCC2" OR filed_name:"GSHS" OR filed_name:"HEL-S-64p" OR filed_name:"HEL-S-88n" OR filed_name:"MLC1" OR filed_name:"LVM" OR filed_name:"VL" OR filed_name:"MLC" OR filed_name:"SPRN" OR filed_name:"CLCN1" OR filed_name:"PPT1" OR filed_name:"CLN1" OR filed_name:"INCL" OR filed_name:"PPT" OR filed_name:"MAPK8IP1" OR filed_name:"ZNF592" OR filed_name:"ATP7A" OR filed_name:"ALS2CR4" OR filed_name:"JBTS14" OR filed_name:"PMPCA" OR filed_name:"ITGB1" OR filed_name:"RFT1" OR filed_name:"STXBP1" OR filed_name:"NPHP3" OR filed_name:"LBR" OR filed_name:"CSPP1" OR filed_name:"UQCRQ" OR filed_name:"QPC" OR filed_name:"MC3DN4" OR filed_name:"QCR8" OR filed_name:"QP-C" OR filed_name:"UQCR7" OR filed_name:"PRDM8" OR filed_name:"DDB2" OR filed_name:"COMMD3-BMI" OR filed_name:"NEU1" OR filed_name:"SLC12A6" OR filed_name:"ACD" OR filed_name:"NFASC" OR filed_name:"KCNV1" OR filed_name:"SLC16A2" OR filed_name:"DXS128" OR filed_name:"XPCT" OR filed_name:"AHDS" OR filed_name:"DXS128E" OR filed_name:"MCT" OR filed_name:"LMX1A" OR filed_name:"AFF1" OR filed_name:"BBS1" OR filed_name:"COX1" OR filed_name:"GS27" OR filed_name:"EPM6" OR filed_name:"Bos1" OR filed_name:"THMD5" OR filed_name:"HTPK1" OR filed_name:"PP20" OR filed_name:"ABCC8" OR filed_name:"USH1C" OR filed_name:"TRNE" OR filed_name:"CISD2" OR filed_name:"GPI" OR filed_name:"CTC1" OR filed_name:"CRMCC" OR filed_name:"C17orf68" OR filed_name:"AAF132" OR filed_name:"AAF-132" OR filed_name:"tmp494178" OR filed_name:"NDUFB9" OR filed_name:"MAFG" OR filed_name:"SGPL1" OR filed_name:"SPL" OR filed_name:"NPHS14" OR filed_name:"S1PL" OR filed_name:"MPDU1" OR filed_name:"NF2" OR filed_name:"PAX7" OR filed_name:"KCNE1B" OR filed_name:"LPIN2" OR filed_name:"HEPACAM" OR filed_name:"PRIP" OR filed_name:"KURU" OR filed_name:"CJD" OR filed_name:"ASCR" OR filed_name:"AltPrP" OR filed_name:"CD230" OR filed_name:"PrP" OR filed_name:"PrP27-30" OR filed_name:"PrP33-35C" OR filed_name:"PrPc" OR filed_name:"p27-30" OR filed_name:"AARS" OR filed_name:"SCN9A" OR filed_name:"USE1" OR filed_name:"SDHC" OR filed_name:"MAPT" OR filed_name:"TRNN" OR filed_name:"RBFOX1" OR filed_name:"SUCLA2" OR filed_name:"ANK3" OR filed_name:"TTL" OR filed_name:"CEP290" OR filed_name:"EBF3" OR filed_name:"COE3" OR filed_name:"HADDS" OR filed_name:"EBF-3" OR filed_name:"O/E-2" OR filed_name:"OE-2" OR filed_name:"MVK" OR filed_name:"RNF168" OR filed_name:"SLC2A1" OR filed_name:"NDUFAF3" OR filed_name:"PTF1A" OR filed_name:"EN1" OR filed_name:"EDNRB" OR filed_name:"PEX12" OR filed_name:"CI-24k" OR filed_name:"TMEM126B" OR filed_name:"HT007" OR filed_name:"2P1" OR filed_name:"C3orf60" OR filed_name:"E3-3" OR filed_name:"NDUFAF4" OR filed_name:"HRPAP20" OR filed_name:"C6orf66" OR filed_name:"HSPC125" OR filed_name:"My013" OR filed_name:"bA22L21.1" OR filed_name:"NUBPL" OR filed_name:"IND1" OR filed_name:"C14orf127" OR filed_name:"huInd1" OR filed_name:"NDUFAF5" OR filed_name:"C20orf7" OR filed_name:"bA526K24.2" OR filed_name:"dJ842G6.1" OR filed_name:"NDUFA1" OR filed_name:"MWFE" OR filed_name:"CI-MWFE" OR filed_name:"ZNF183" OR filed_name:"NDUFS2" OR filed_name:"CI-49" OR filed_name:"NDUFB11" OR filed_name:"LSDMCA3" OR filed_name:"CI-ESSS" OR filed_name:"ESSS" OR filed_name:"NP17.3" OR filed_name:"Np15" OR filed_name:"P17.3" OR filed_name:"TIMMDC1" OR filed_name:"C3orf1" OR filed_name:"B12" OR filed_name:"CI-B12" OR filed_name:"UQOR1" OR filed_name:"CI-51K" OR filed_name:"CI51KD" OR filed_name:"NDUFS6" OR filed_name:"CI-13kA" OR filed_name:"CI-13kD-A" OR filed_name:"CI13KDA" OR filed_name:"UQOR22" OR filed_name:"B22" OR filed_name:"CI-B22" OR filed_name:"LYRM3" OR filed_name:"NDUFS1" OR filed_name:"CI-75Kd" OR filed_name:"CI-75k" OR filed_name:"PRO1304" OR filed_name:"NDUFAF1" OR filed_name:"CIA30" OR filed_name:"CGI65" OR filed_name:"CGI-65" OR filed_name:"B14.7" OR filed_name:"CI-B14.7" OR filed_name:"MAFK" OR filed_name:"THRA" OR filed_name:"HCN1" OR filed_name:"SYT2" OR filed_name:"TBP" OR filed_name:"KISS1R" OR filed_name:"RAD50" OR filed_name:"CLN6" OR filed_name:"SLC52A3" OR filed_name:"MTP" OR filed_name:"ABL" OR filed_name:"SPR" OR filed_name:"SDR38C1" OR filed_name:"CEP120" OR filed_name:"PSMG1" OR filed_name:"TRNH" OR filed_name:"HSCO" OR filed_name:"D83198" OR filed_name:"YF13H12" OR filed_name:"GALC" OR filed_name:"ACO2" OR filed_name:"ICRD" OR filed_name:"OPA9" OR filed_name:"ACONM" OR filed_name:"HEL-S-284" OR filed_name:"OCA8" OR filed_name:"ZIC4" OR filed_name:"ATF2" OR filed_name:"HESX1" OR filed_name:"ASAL" OR filed_name:"OFD1" OR filed_name:"PLCB4" OR filed_name:"CNP" OR filed_name:"DYRK1A" OR filed_name:"MNBH" OR filed_name:"MNB" OR filed_name:"MRD7" OR filed_name:"DYRK" OR filed_name:"DYRK1" OR filed_name:"HP86" OR filed_name:"RARS" OR filed_name:"HLD9" OR filed_name:"ArgRS" OR filed_name:"DALRD1" OR filed_name:"CIB2" OR filed_name:"GMPPB" OR filed_name:"KIAA1851" OR filed_name:"MDDGA14" OR filed_name:"MDDGB14" OR filed_name:"MDDGC14" OR filed_name:"FEZF1" OR filed_name:"IQCB1" OR filed_name:"ND6" OR filed_name:"ACP2" OR filed_name:"NANS" OR filed_name:"PNP" OR filed_name:"CLN5" OR filed_name:"NCL" OR filed_name:"RORA" OR filed_name:"NKX2-1" OR filed_name:"CNTNAP1" OR filed_name:"DBCN" OR filed_name:"LISX" OR filed_name:"DC" OR filed_name:"SCLH" OR filed_name:"XLIS" OR filed_name:"YME1L1" OR filed_name:"YME1L" OR filed_name:"PAMP" OR filed_name:"OPA11" OR filed_name:"FTSH" OR filed_name:"MEG4" OR filed_name:"PARN" OR filed_name:"HLCS" OR filed_name:"PROK2" OR filed_name:"INPP4A" OR filed_name:"TCTN2" OR filed_name:"TECT2" OR filed_name:"MKS8" OR filed_name:"JBTS24" OR filed_name:"C12orf38" OR filed_name:"TRNI" OR filed_name:"MAPK8IP2" OR filed_name:"MBP" OR filed_name:"PBD8A" OR filed_name:"PBD8B" OR filed_name:"IL10" OR filed_name:"RUNX3" OR filed_name:"NTF3" OR filed_name:"CLN2" OR filed_name:"SCAR7" OR filed_name:"GIG1" OR filed_name:"LPIC" OR filed_name:"TPP-1" OR filed_name:"CAMK2B" OR filed_name:"PTCH1" OR filed_name:"AAAS" OR filed_name:"RBFOX2" OR filed_name:"DHFR" OR filed_name:"AMACR" OR filed_name:"MYF5" OR filed_name:"HLA-DQB1" OR filed_name:"CELIAC1" OR filed_name:"HLA-DQB" OR filed_name:"IDDM1" OR filed_name:"HLA-DQA1" OR filed_name:"DQ-A1" OR filed_name:"HLA-DQA" OR filed_name:"APOB" OR filed_name:"FLDB" OR filed_name:"LDLCQ4" OR filed_name:"apoB-100" OR filed_name:"apoB-48" OR filed_name:"TERT" OR filed_name:"MKS3" OR filed_name:"JBTS6" OR filed_name:"NPHP11" OR filed_name:"MECKELIN" OR filed_name:"TNEM67" OR filed_name:"KIAA1345" OR filed_name:"MKS6" OR filed_name:"JBTS9" OR filed_name:"ZIC1" OR filed_name:"SLC31A1" OR filed_name:"IL12A-AS1" OR filed_name:"NRCAM" OR filed_name:"TRNQ" OR filed_name:"TANGO2" OR filed_name:"EPM2A" OR filed_name:"PEX13" OR filed_name:"CDH23" OR filed_name:"C5ORF42" OR filed_name:"DNASE1L3" OR filed_name:"HYLS1" OR filed_name:"IREB2" OR filed_name:"C4A" OR filed_name:"CDG1N" OR filed_name:"INVS" OR filed_name:"SNORD118" OR filed_name:"LCC" OR filed_name:"U8" OR filed_name:"AARS2" OR filed_name:"XPAC" OR filed_name:"XP1" OR filed_name:"GTPBP2" OR filed_name:"COL18A1" OR filed_name:"PCNA" OR filed_name:"ATLD2" OR filed_name:"PNKP" OR filed_name:"PNK" OR filed_name:"MCSZ" OR filed_name:"EIEE10" OR filed_name:"AOA4" OR filed_name:"OGDH" OR filed_name:"BBS2L2" OR filed_name:"CCDC28B" OR filed_name:"MGC1203" OR filed_name:"ARL6" OR filed_name:"BBS3" OR filed_name:"RP55" OR filed_name:"VAC14" OR filed_name:"C19orf12" OR filed_name:"NBIA4" OR filed_name:"SPG43" OR filed_name:"MPAN" OR filed_name:"NBIA3" OR filed_name:"POLR3B" OR filed_name:"ABCA5" OR filed_name:"RUBCN" OR filed_name:"TLR4" OR filed_name:"NBN" OR filed_name:"APP" OR filed_name:"GLDN" OR filed_name:"RRM2B" OR filed_name:"SPG11" OR filed_name:"APBA1" OR filed_name:"NOTCH3" OR filed_name:"AIFM1" OR filed_name:"GPX4" OR filed_name:"ITPR1" OR filed_name:"SCA15" OR filed_name:"SCA16" OR filed_name:"SCA29" OR filed_name:"ACV" OR filed_name:"CLA4" OR filed_name:"INSP3R1" OR filed_name:"IP3R" OR filed_name:"IP3R1" OR filed_name:"PPP1R94" OR filed_name:"MYO7A" OR filed_name:"KCNA1" OR filed_name:"DOCK3" OR filed_name:"POLR3A" OR filed_name:"BBS4" OR filed_name:"PRSS11" OR filed_name:"ARMD7" OR filed_name:"CARASIL" OR filed_name:"CADASIL2" OR filed_name:"HtrA" OR filed_name:"L56" OR filed_name:"ORF480" OR filed_name:"NCK1" OR filed_name:"COXPD15" OR filed_name:"FMT1" OR filed_name:"NF1" OR filed_name:"LRPPRC" OR filed_name:"LRP130" OR filed_name:"LSFC" OR filed_name:"CLONE-23970" OR filed_name:"GP130" OR filed_name:"STFB" OR filed_name:"EPM1" OR filed_name:"PME" OR filed_name:"EPM1A" OR filed_name:"ULD" OR filed_name:"CPI-B" OR filed_name:"CST6" OR filed_name:"KIF14" OR filed_name:"GMPPA" OR filed_name:"KCNMA1" OR filed_name:"LAMA4" OR filed_name:"ELP1" OR filed_name:"TRAPPC11" OR filed_name:"FA2H" OR filed_name:"FAAH" OR filed_name:"FAXDC1" OR filed_name:"FAH1" OR filed_name:"SCS7" OR filed_name:"SPG35" OR filed_name:"FAAH-1" OR filed_name:"PSAB" OR filed_name:"SLC9A1" OR filed_name:"WDR73" OR filed_name:"NXF1" OR filed_name:"SCN8A" OR filed_name:"UBE3A" OR filed_name:"DPM1" OR filed_name:"MECR" OR filed_name:"NRBF1" OR filed_name:"DYTOABG" OR filed_name:"CGI-63" OR filed_name:"FASN2B" OR filed_name:"ITPA" OR filed_name:"MYO5A" OR filed_name:"MKSR1" OR filed_name:"MKS9" OR filed_name:"JBTS27" OR filed_name:"B9" OR filed_name:"EPPB9" OR filed_name:"AUH" OR filed_name:"GLUT1" OR filed_name:"HTLVR" OR filed_name:"DYT18" OR filed_name:"PED" OR filed_name:"GLUT1DS" OR filed_name:"EIG12" OR filed_name:"DYT9" OR filed_name:"SDCHCN" OR filed_name:"CSE" OR filed_name:"DYT17" OR filed_name:"GLUT" OR filed_name:"GLUT-1" OR filed_name:"NSMF" OR filed_name:"TSC1" OR filed_name:"PFDN5" OR filed_name:"EPMR" OR filed_name:"C8orf61" OR filed_name:"GAMT" OR filed_name:"PGK1" OR filed_name:"SLC6A19" OR filed_name:"VARS2" OR filed_name:"MCOLN1" OR filed_name:"ASPA" OR filed_name:"WFRS" OR filed_name:"WFS" OR filed_name:"DFNA6" OR filed_name:"DFNA14" OR filed_name:"DFNA38" OR filed_name:"WFSL" OR filed_name:"CTRCT41" OR filed_name:"RBL1" OR filed_name:"SLC25A46" OR filed_name:"HMSN6B" OR filed_name:"PEX14" OR filed_name:"TACR3" OR filed_name:"HPRT1" OR filed_name:"PHYH" OR filed_name:"TRNW" OR filed_name:"APBA2" OR filed_name:"TSGA14" OR filed_name:"JBTS15" OR filed_name:"CDC42" OR filed_name:"BSCL2" OR filed_name:"TRNP" OR filed_name:"FGF8" OR filed_name:"ABHD12" OR filed_name:"BDNF" OR filed_name:"HPGDS" OR filed_name:"KIAA1270" OR filed_name:"MTALARS" OR filed_name:"COXPD8" OR filed_name:"LKENP" OR filed_name:"AARSL" OR filed_name:"MT-ALARS" OR filed_name:"ATP7B" OR filed_name:"TDP1" OR filed_name:"MKS" OR filed_name:"BBS13" OR filed_name:"JBTS28" OR filed_name:"MES" OR filed_name:"POC12" OR filed_name:"AHI-1" OR filed_name:"JBTS3" OR filed_name:"ORF1" OR filed_name:"dJ71N10.1" OR filed_name:"ATG5" OR filed_name:"CCM2" OR filed_name:"TTR" OR filed_name:"PALB" OR filed_name:"CTS" OR filed_name:"CTS1" OR filed_name:"HEL111" OR filed_name:"HsT2651" OR filed_name:"TBPA" OR filed_name:"CKN2" OR filed_name:"COFS1" OR filed_name:"CSB" OR filed_name:"ARMD5" OR filed_name:"UVSS1" OR filed_name:"POF11" OR filed_name:"COFS" OR filed_name:"RAD26" OR filed_name:"PROKR2" OR filed_name:"PLXNA2" OR filed_name:"MGA3" OR filed_name:"ATP8" OR filed_name:"SIL1" OR filed_name:"ABCD1" OR filed_name:"SLC12A2" OR filed_name:"CERS1" OR filed_name:"NENA" OR filed_name:"PN1" OR filed_name:"FEB3B" OR filed_name:"GEFSP7" OR filed_name:"SFNP" OR filed_name:"HSAN2D" OR filed_name:"ETHA" OR filed_name:"NE-NA" OR filed_name:"Nav1.7" OR filed_name:"GEFSP2" OR filed_name:"SMEI" OR filed_name:"FEB3A" OR filed_name:"EIEE6" OR filed_name:"FHM3" OR filed_name:"FEB3" OR filed_name:"HBSCI" OR filed_name:"NAC1" OR filed_name:"Nav1.1" OR filed_name:"SCN1" OR filed_name:"VRK1" OR filed_name:"PCH1A" OR filed_name:"PCH1" OR filed_name:"TMEM216" OR filed_name:"AAA" OR filed_name:"AAASb" OR filed_name:"ADRACALA" OR filed_name:"ADRACALIN" OR filed_name:"ALADIN" OR filed_name:"GL003" OR filed_name:"PROM1" OR filed_name:"ATP12" OR filed_name:"MC5DN1" OR filed_name:"ATP12p" OR filed_name:"LP3663" OR filed_name:"NCK2" OR filed_name:"DDIT3" OR filed_name:"HMBS" OR filed_name:"TRIM2" OR filed_name:"KAT2A" OR filed_name:"MRXSCS" OR filed_name:"ALDH5A1" OR filed_name:"PIK3R5" OR filed_name:"p101" OR filed_name:"F730038I15Rik" OR filed_name:"FOAP-2" OR filed_name:"P101-PI3K" OR filed_name:"ADA2" OR filed_name:"CECR1" OR filed_name:"PAN" OR filed_name:"SNEDS" OR filed_name:"ADGF" OR filed_name:"IDGFL" OR filed_name:"SMARCB1" OR filed_name:"FXN" OR filed_name:"CLP1" OR filed_name:"DEL15q11.2" OR filed_name:"C15DELq11.2" OR filed_name:"MSI1" OR filed_name:"RTEL1" OR filed_name:"GNAQ" OR filed_name:"HCN2" OR filed_name:"PTGDR" OR filed_name:"QKI" OR filed_name:"EM9" OR filed_name:"XPD" OR filed_name:"COFS2" OR filed_name:"TTD1" OR filed_name:"TTD" OR filed_name:"NPC1" OR filed_name:"GNB5" OR filed_name:"CBLN1" OR filed_name:"PXAAA1" OR filed_name:"PAF2" OR filed_name:"PBD4A" OR filed_name:"PDB4B" OR filed_name:"HMLR2" OR filed_name:"PAF-2" OR filed_name:"ARV1" OR filed_name:"EIEE38" OR filed_name:"ITM2B" OR filed_name:"BRI" OR filed_name:"ABRI" OR filed_name:"FBD" OR filed_name:"RDGCA" OR filed_name:"BRI2" OR filed_name:"BRICD2B" OR filed_name:"E25B" OR filed_name:"E3-16" OR filed_name:"imBRI2" OR filed_name:"PEX26" OR filed_name:"PDZD7" OR filed_name:"KIAA0586" OR filed_name:"CACNB4" OR filed_name:"PEX7" OR filed_name:"CTDP1" OR filed_name:"KCNA2" OR filed_name:"PMP22" OR filed_name:"USH1G" OR filed_name:"SPG17" OR filed_name:"HMN5" OR filed_name:"PELD" OR filed_name:"GNG3LG" OR filed_name:"EPM10" OR filed_name:"KMT8D" OR filed_name:"PFM5" OR filed_name:"CAMK4" OR filed_name:"SCAX5" OR filed_name:"NUMB" OR filed_name:"LYRM8" OR filed_name:"PGL1" OR filed_name:"CWS3" OR filed_name:"CBT1" OR filed_name:"CII-4" OR filed_name:"PGL" OR filed_name:"QPs3" OR filed_name:"SDH4" OR filed_name:"cybS" OR filed_name:"STX1B" OR filed_name:"LETM1" OR filed_name:"PEX19" OR filed_name:"GLRA1" OR filed_name:"CBLN3" OR filed_name:"EIEE32" OR filed_name:"HBK5" OR filed_name:"HK4" OR filed_name:"HUKIV" OR filed_name:"KV1.2" OR filed_name:"MK2" OR filed_name:"NGK1" OR filed_name:"RBK2" OR filed_name:"SKOR2" OR filed_name:"TM7SF2" OR filed_name:"RNR1" OR filed_name:"TUBA1A" OR filed_name:"STAT1" OR filed_name:"GBA1" OR filed_name:"GCB" OR filed_name:"GLUC" OR filed_name:"MRE11A" OR filed_name:"JBTS2" OR filed_name:"CORS2" OR filed_name:"MKS2" OR filed_name:"HSPC244" OR filed_name:"TUBA3" OR filed_name:"LIS3" OR filed_name:"B-ALPHA-1" OR filed_name:"MPV17" OR filed_name:"ROBO3" OR filed_name:"NLK" OR filed_name:"SMPD1" OR filed_name:"CAMTA1" OR filed_name:"KIAA0833" OR filed_name:"CANPMR" OR filed_name:"UBAC2" OR filed_name:"MYRF" OR filed_name:"PSAP" OR filed_name:"ERCC8" OR filed_name:"MLC2A" OR filed_name:"MLC2B" OR filed_name:"GlialCAM" OR filed_name:"PIK3CA" OR filed_name:"ERBB2" OR filed_name:"ACN" OR filed_name:"BANF" OR filed_name:"SCH" OR filed_name:"MEFV" OR filed_name:"FGF17" OR filed_name:"ATP1A3" OR filed_name:"PGKA" OR filed_name:"HEL-S-68p" OR filed_name:"MIG10" OR filed_name:"MED13L" OR filed_name:"CX43" OR filed_name:"ODDD" OR filed_name:"SDTY3" OR filed_name:"ODOD" OR filed_name:"AVSD3" OR filed_name:"HLHS1" OR filed_name:"CMDR" OR filed_name:"EKVP3" OR filed_name:"EKVP" OR filed_name:"GJAL" OR filed_name:"PPKCA" OR filed_name:"PHARC" OR filed_name:"ABHD12A" OR filed_name:"BEM46L2" OR filed_name:"C20orf22" OR filed_name:"dJ965G21.2" OR filed_name:"COX2" OR filed_name:"TDP2" OR filed_name:"TITF1" OR filed_name:"NKX2A" OR filed_name:"TTF1" OR filed_name:"NMTC1" OR filed_name:"BCH" OR filed_name:"BHC" OR filed_name:"NK-2" OR filed_name:"NKX2.1" OR filed_name:"T/EBP" OR filed_name:"TEBP" OR filed_name:"TTF-1" OR filed_name:"TTF-I" OR filed_name:"SSADH" OR filed_name:"SSDH" OR filed_name:"TBCE" OR filed_name:"KCS" OR filed_name:"KCS1" OR filed_name:"HRD" OR filed_name:"PEAMO" OR filed_name:"pac2" OR filed_name:"PAX6" OR filed_name:"DNMT1" OR filed_name:"WHRN" OR filed_name:"CKN1" OR filed_name:"CSA" OR filed_name:"UVSS2" OR filed_name:"XRCC1" OR filed_name:"SLC7A10" OR filed_name:"NFIX" OR filed_name:"GRIA3" OR filed_name:"ASS" OR filed_name:"CTLN1" OR filed_name:"RB1" OR filed_name:"PEX3" OR filed_name:"CPAT1" OR filed_name:"ACP" OR filed_name:"SEMA3A" OR filed_name:"IKBKAP" OR filed_name:"CYP27A1" OR filed_name:"IFIT2" OR filed_name:"CALB1" OR filed_name:"IPLA2" OR filed_name:"INAD1" OR filed_name:"NBIA2B" OR filed_name:"NBIA2A" OR filed_name:"PARK14" OR filed_name:"CaI-PLA2" OR filed_name:"GVI" OR filed_name:"IPLA2-VIA" OR filed_name:"NBIA2" OR filed_name:"PLA2" OR filed_name:"PNPLA9" OR filed_name:"iPLA2" OR filed_name:"iPLA2beta" OR filed_name:"TUBB5" OR filed_name:"M40" OR filed_name:"CDCBM6" OR filed_name:"CSCSC1" OR filed_name:"OK/SW-cl.56" OR filed_name:"TUBB1" OR filed_name:"CFL1" OR filed_name:"DNM1" OR filed_name:"ATG7" OR filed_name:"CP-2" OR filed_name:"NAPB" OR filed_name:"PPP2R1A" OR filed_name:"SEC23B" OR filed_name:"F3" OR filed_name:"ITGAV" OR filed_name:"MTDPS6" OR filed_name:"SYM1" OR filed_name:"LMBRD1" OR filed_name:"MFSD2A" OR filed_name:"ABCD2" OR filed_name:"ARHGAP10" OR filed_name:"TMEM176B" OR filed_name:"DARS2" OR filed_name:"ASPRS.LBSL" OR filed_name:"ASPRS" OR filed_name:"LBSL" OR filed_name:"MT-ASPRS" OR filed_name:"CLRN1" OR filed_name:"E2F5" OR filed_name:"SHH" OR filed_name:"RPIA" OR filed_name:"GPM6B" OR filed_name:"E2F6" OR filed_name:"FCP1" OR filed_name:"CCFDN" OR filed_name:"FCP" OR filed_name:"FCPX" OR filed_name:"HBFQTL3" OR filed_name:"SYNE1" OR filed_name:"NP" OR filed_name:"PRO1837" OR filed_name:"PUNP" OR filed_name:"SPTBN2" OR filed_name:"RND3" OR filed_name:"SLC4A2" OR filed_name:"DYT12" OR filed_name:"RDP" OR filed_name:"AHC2" OR filed_name:"CAPOS" OR filed_name:"ATP1A1" OR filed_name:"NEUROD1" OR filed_name:"CHP1" OR filed_name:"HNRNPH2" OR filed_name:"NRPH2" OR filed_name:"MRXSB" OR filed_name:"FTP3" OR filed_name:"HNRPH" OR filed_name:"HNRPH2" OR filed_name:"hnRNPH" OR filed_name:"SL15" OR filed_name:"CDGIF" OR filed_name:"HBEBP2BPA" OR filed_name:"Lec35" OR filed_name:"My008" OR filed_name:"PP3958" OR filed_name:"PQLC5" OR filed_name:"C12ORF65" OR filed_name:"OLIG2" OR filed_name:"TRIO" OR filed_name:"SCNM1" OR filed_name:"USH2A" OR filed_name:"KIAA0373" OR filed_name:"3H11AG" OR filed_name:"JBTS5" OR filed_name:"SLSN6" OR filed_name:"LCA10" OR filed_name:"BBS14" OR filed_name:"3H11Ag" OR filed_name:"CT87" OR filed_name:"MKS4" OR filed_name:"NPHP6" OR filed_name:"POC3" OR filed_name:"rd16" OR filed_name:"LCAP" OR filed_name:"TMC1" OR filed_name:"TSC2" OR filed_name:"AP5Z1" OR filed_name:"KIAA0415" OR filed_name:"SPG48" OR filed_name:"zeta" OR filed_name:"ATXN1" OR filed_name:"UGCG" OR filed_name:"COQ8A" OR filed_name:"GRN" OR filed_name:"CLN11" OR filed_name:"GEP" OR filed_name:"GP88" OR filed_name:"PCDGF" OR filed_name:"PEPI" OR filed_name:"PGRN" OR filed_name:"MAP2K4" OR filed_name:"NUP107" OR filed_name:"BID" OR filed_name:"RC3" OR filed_name:"KIAA0856" OR filed_name:"PEPNS" OR filed_name:"DFNA71" OR filed_name:"SLC30A9" OR filed_name:"C4orf1" OR filed_name:"HUEL" OR filed_name:"BILAPES" OR filed_name:"GAC63" OR filed_name:"ZNT9" OR filed_name:"FGF12" OR filed_name:"GBE1" OR filed_name:"PEX11B" OR filed_name:"KIAA1840" OR filed_name:"FLJ21439" OR filed_name:"ALS5" OR filed_name:"CMT2X" OR filed_name:"GRIA4" OR filed_name:"ALD" OR filed_name:"AMN" OR filed_name:"ABC42" OR filed_name:"ALDP" OR filed_name:"PRO1028" OR filed_name:"amnionless" OR filed_name:"EPB41L3" OR filed_name:"HARS" OR filed_name:"KIF1A" OR filed_name:"BLOC1S6" OR filed_name:"KCNJ6" OR filed_name:"PRF1" OR filed_name:"PPT2" OR filed_name:"ROGDI" OR filed_name:"BEAN1" OR filed_name:"C19ORF12" OR filed_name:"AGM1" OR filed_name:"IMD23" OR filed_name:"PAGM" OR filed_name:"PGM" OR filed_name:"PEX2" OR filed_name:"LYRM7" OR filed_name:"MZM1L" OR filed_name:"MC3DN8" OR filed_name:"C5orf31" OR filed_name:"CDKN1B" OR filed_name:"SMAD2" OR filed_name:"APLP2" OR filed_name:"VPS13A" OR filed_name:"FLRT3" OR filed_name:"ATP2B2" OR filed_name:"CDG1A" OR filed_name:"CDG1" OR filed_name:"CDG1a" OR filed_name:"CDGS" OR filed_name:"PMI" OR filed_name:"PMI1" OR filed_name:"PMM" OR filed_name:"TMEM70" OR filed_name:"SAS" OR filed_name:"SEMDCG" OR filed_name:"HEL-S-100" OR filed_name:"SEMDG" OR filed_name:"GRIN1" OR filed_name:"PDSS2" OR filed_name:"C4orf41" OR filed_name:"LGMD2S" OR filed_name:"FOIGR" OR filed_name:"GRY" OR filed_name:"HDL3" OR filed_name:"HLN2" OR filed_name:"ADAM22" OR filed_name:"TUBB4A" OR filed_name:"DYT4" OR filed_name:"HLD6" OR filed_name:"TUBB4" OR filed_name:"beta-5" OR filed_name:"HS6ST1" OR filed_name:"CCDS2" OR filed_name:"HEL-S-20" OR filed_name:"PIG2" OR filed_name:"TP53I2" OR filed_name:"HYDIN" OR filed_name:"MLD" OR filed_name:"DHFRP1" OR filed_name:"DYR" OR filed_name:"WNT1" OR filed_name:"AKT1" OR filed_name:"TAF1" OR filed_name:"FBXL4" OR filed_name:"HPLH2" OR filed_name:"FLH2" OR filed_name:"P1" OR filed_name:"PFN1" OR filed_name:"PFP" OR filed_name:"SLC6A8" OR filed_name:"KTZS" OR filed_name:"PTPN22" OR filed_name:"ADAM23" OR filed_name:"ATCAY" OR filed_name:"hRNF168" OR filed_name:"CACNG2" OR filed_name:"RHBDF1" OR filed_name:"CACNL1A4" OR filed_name:"SCA6" OR filed_name:"EIEE42" OR filed_name:"APCA" OR filed_name:"BI" OR filed_name:"CAV2.1" OR filed_name:"EA2" OR filed_name:"FHM" OR filed_name:"HPCA" OR filed_name:"MHP" OR filed_name:"MHP1" OR filed_name:"IL17RD" OR filed_name:"LRP8" OR filed_name:"TMEM231" OR filed_name:"CACNA2D2" OR filed_name:"TMEM107" OR filed_name:"MKS13" OR filed_name:"JBTS29" OR filed_name:"GRVS638" OR filed_name:"PRO1268" OR filed_name:"NR5A1" OR filed_name:"NEUROD2" OR filed_name:"STK36" )',
                                "analyze_wildcard" => 1,
                            )
                ),

                "sort" => Array
                    (
                        "sort_order" => Array
                            (
                                "order" => 'asc',
                            ),

                        "record_score" => Array
                            (
                                "order" => 'desc',
                            ),

                    ),

                "aggs" => Array
                    (
                        "variant_count" => Array
                            (
                                "cardinality" => Array
                                    (
                                        "field" => 'field_name1',
                                        "precision_threshold" => 40000,
                                    )

                            ),

                        "gene_count" => Array
                            (
                                "cardinality" => Array
                                    (
                                        "field" => 'filed_name',
                                        "precision_threshold" => 40000,
                                    )

                            ),

                        "gene_list" => Array
                            (
                                "terms" => Array
                                    (
                                        "field" => 'filed_name',
                                    )

                            )

                    ),

            ),

        "size" => 500,
        "from" => 0,
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this issue. Add the below setting in your elasticsearch.yml  or add it in the index setting.

```
indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 2048
```

if you are adding it in elasticsearch.yml file dont forget to restart the node.